# The term “Configuration” in quantum field theory, what does it mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology

I would like a thorough explanation of what the word [“configuration”](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=configuration+physics), means, as used in ‘Quantum Field Theory’.

I have seen the word used in various phrases, such as “the field configuration φ(x)”, “given initial configuration” and possibly “integrate over all configurations”.

I have some knowledge of non-relativistic quantum theory.

Could your answer include the use of the idea “configuration” being used in various equations starting with something simple? Perhaps you could refer me to where I might find such an answer?

Answer (score 2):

A field configuration is simply a particular set of values for the field at every point in space. For example, a particular configuration for the 0+1-dimensional field $f(x)$ might be $f(x)=x^2$, or $f(x)=e^{-x}$, or even some arbitrarily complex form that isn't describable with elementary functions.

The point is that a field configuration is simply a "point in function-space". The exact definition of "function-space" imposes restrictions on the kind of configurations such a field can adopt (for example, due to UV cutoffs, QFTs cannot admit large fluctuations on very small length scales; we also typically ask that the configurations vanish at infinity or conform to some other boundary condition). When you integrate over all field configurations, you are integrating in function-space over all allowed points, or equivalently integrating over all of the functions that your field could possibly be.

Comment: But a quantum field is an operator not a function.

Comment: A quantum field is an operator that results from the promotion of a classical field, which is a function. A configuration of a quantum field is the operator promotion of the configuration of the corresponding classical field. Alternatively, operators can also be functions of spacetime; their "value" at a particular point in spacetime can be defined as, say, the value of a particular matrix representation at that point.